# Press backspace to delete more than one character while input from keyboard

Tags: java

Here what I want to achieve, before press "enter" when user types a double number, maybe users think that they need to type again, so press backspace is a necessary thing to do to delete the previous character.
But if you delete the 1st decimal figure, it will delete the decimal point at the same time, my teacher said that will show to user that can be an integer value.
I think this event may related to "System.in", but i still can't find out.

this is my Main class code:

```java
    private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            double result = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine().trim());
            System.out.println("Output : " + result);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("> INPUT MUST BE DOUBLE NUMBER...");
        }
    }
```

For example: on output window, you enter "7.89" (Not press enter, still on input).
When you press backspace input will be "7.8", and you press backspace one more time, it will be "7", at that time it will delete both "8" and decimal point. and when press enter output is "7"

My Question: how to delete the decimal point from the on-screen input?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: You have no control over that. Not with `Scanner` at least.

Comment: Why do you need to know that the user hit backspace? `7` is a valid `double` value.

Comment: You can make it easier for you and just use the built-in `Scanner.nextDouble()` function.

Comment: OP is asking how to delete the decimal point from the **on-screen input**, not from the resulting value read by `Scanner`. Or at least that's how I'm interpreting "When you press backspace input will be "7.8", and you press backspace one more time, it will be "7", at that time it will delete both "8" and decimal point." @NathanLe, please clarify

Comment: That doesn't happen on my Windows box. When I delete the `8` the decimal is still there - as I would expect. OP definitely needs to clarify.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I mean that they *want* the dot automatically removed when they remove the digit after it, not that it *does* happen.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Ah. I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regex and the eol anchor to replace the end . by ""

or just check if input.endsWith(".")